# Background Image Fully Covered

Tags: html, css

I've got several divs on my webpage with background images. Currently it's what I want, but with white borders on the side and top/bottom (for those divs at the top/bottom of page).

This is the current situation:

[My webpage - notice slight white border around photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w65Ix.jpg)

I'm trying to get it to fill the browser (instead of having borders), but none of the other suggestions are working for me. Below is my code for one div:

```
<div class="header-image">
    <img src="smesh-colour-hires.png">  
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.header-image {
    background-image: url("animals-deep-ocean-deep-sea-130621.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.header-image img{
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

Let me know if anything doesn't make sense and I'll try my best to explain.

Any help would be much appreciated, this is really blocking me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white border is probably due to the default margin on the `body`.

Try adding this in your CSS.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Ahh sorry, such an easy solution - much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your CSS

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```